# How to manage my directory's in asp.net using fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload, directory

Please take some of your time and read my problem
I need by using fileupload to upload just images to my web application
But when I select the image and click on upload button if the program see it a jpg file it will create a directory with the name jpg an save it there
That goes to gif and png 
Please any one if you could give the code I will be very very thankful to you
Or at least link could help me

```
string folder = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

            string path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/" + folder;
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            string server_path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/myfiles/";

            FileUpload1.SaveAs(server_path + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Comment: That's what it is doing, or that's what you want it to do? You'll need to post some code to show where you are having trouble.

Comment: Ok wait a minute

Comment: I published my code

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName); to get the extension of the file.

Comment: The problem is not in the file the problem is in the path

Answer (score 0):

Physical path for the virtual directory using:

System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(virtualDirectoryPath)